# Created ".asoundrc" file manually , can't compile and error shown "bash: .asoundrc: syntax error unexpected token '}'

Tags: bash, source

Nice to meet you.

(Using Environment)
Ubuntu: 20.04.03 LTS
shell : bash

Example info  :  https://github.com/mixxxdj/mixxx/wiki/traktor_audio_2

I created ".asoundrc" file manually, following code.

```
pcm.TraktorAudio2Master {type plug; slave.pcm "hw:TraktorAudio2,0,0";}
pcm.TraktorAudio2Headphones {type plug; slave.pcm "hw:TraktorAudio2,0,1";}
```

When I compile by  `source .asoundrc` a file, an error message shown up everytime.

```
bash: .asoundrc: Syntax error, unexpected token '}' Line 1
```

At first I suspected "CR+LF" code and removed by vi command `%s/^M//g`
but still shows same error.

I can't solve this problem(what's the format wrong).

Comment: AFAIK a `.asoundrc` file isn't a shell script, so it isn't meant to be sourced into a shell. Why do you believe you need to "compile" it in this way? are you following some kind of tutorial that suggests this?

Comment: Thanks for your responding.
I thought that it needs "source" command like ".bashrc"  file.

Comment: I don't think so - it is intended to be read and processed by the `asound` / `arecord` etc. programs at run time